# DynamicILInfo.GetTokenFor(MethodHandle,RuntimeTypeHandle) does not work for vararg method calls

Tags: c#, .net, clr, dynamicmethod, dynamic-method

Consider following code:

```
    static public void TestMethodVarArgs(__arglist)
    {
        ArgIterator iterator = new ArgIterator(__arglist);
        Console.WriteLine(iterator.GetRemainingCount());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMethodVarArgs(__arglist(2, "asas", 55.0));
    }
```

It seems that `DynamicILInfo.GetTokenFor(MethodHandle,RuntimeTypeHandle)` does not work for vararg method calls (the call to `TestMethodVarArgs` in above code). If I execute the dynamic method, it gives a "JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation" exception.

Is this a bug? Limitation? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Could you show us the code that calls `GetTokenFor()`? Also, why are you even using vararg? Wouldn't using `params object[] args` be better than using undocumented features of the compiler?

Comment: @svick - The code is quite complicated, so I cannot isolate it as a repro case. Also, I am aware about params, but this question is varargs :-)